# The constructor in the MyApp class, calls the provider only once

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I need to call in each of the pages, the connection status of the wifi.
Then use a provider, but in the MyApp(app.component.ts) constructor, call the provider(ConectivityServiceProvider) only once.

app.component.ts

```
import { ConectivityServiceProvider } from '...'
import { Network } from '.....';
export class MyApp {
  conectivity:boolean
  constructor(private provider: ConectivityServiceProvider,public network: Network){
     platform.ready().then(() => {
       this.conectivity=provider.isOnline();
       // call once in all pages
       if(this.conectivity){
          //do someting
       }else //do something
     }
  }
}
```

Provider:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConectivityServiceProvider {
statusConectivity: boolean =true;
constructor(public network: Network){
     this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
        this.statusConectivity=false;
      });
}
isOnline(){
    return this.statusConectivity;
  }
}
```

If I put everything inside the provider in the MyApp class, it does call in each of the pages and not just once.
Why using the provider only calls once?

Comment: You should provide `ConectivityServiceProvider` to your `page.ts` and there call it.

Comment: @distante, In case I have many pages I think it was not the best option.

Comment: Use an app initializer

Answer (score 1):

You should check Ionic [lifecycle events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)

From your description looks loke you have 3 options:

- **ionViewDidLoad**    - void  Runs when the page has loaded. This event only happens once per page being created. If a page leaves but is cached, then this event will not fire again on a subsequent viewing. The ionViewDidLoad event is good place to put your setup code for the page.
- **ionViewWillEnter**  - void  Runs when the page is about to enter and become the active page.
- **ionViewDidEnter**   - void  Runs when the page has fully entered and is now the active page. This event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached page.

So depending what is your approach to case when you loose connection you could use *ionViewDidLoad* to check on every initial load of the page or *ionViewWillEnter* to check it before every time page is displayed (that includes eg. back operations).

Code in `app.component.ts` would look like this:

```
import { ConectivityServiceProvider } from '...'
import { Network } from '.....';

export class MyApp
{
    conectivity: boolean;

    constructor(private provider: ConectivityServiceProvider, public network: Network)
    {
        platform.ready().then(() =>
        {
        });
    }

    ionViewDidLoad()
    {
        this.conectivity = provider.isOnline();
        // call once in all pages
        if(this.conectivity)
        {
            //do someting
        }
        else //do something
        {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Perfect, but I want the service, check if there is connectivity in all the pages I tried it but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Please try angular's [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor#httpinterceptor)

An interceptor intercepts each of the API calls in the app.So before each of the API call we can check the status of the connection and handle the code accordingly.

Refer: [Capture requests globally in angular 4 and stop if no internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46803534/capture-requests-globally-in-angular-4-and-stop-if-no-internet)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ConectivityServiceProvider implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // check to see if there's internet
        if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
            // if there is no internet, throw a HttpErrorResponse error
            // since an error is thrown, the function will terminate here
            return Observable.throw(new HttpErrorResponse({ error: 'Internet is required.' }));

        } else {
            // else return the normal request
            return next.handle(request);
        }
    }
}
```